Why 'ng version' respond with an empty line?
... Along with all other ng commands.
Hi!
I have just reinstalled node.js because was having this issue, and it persisted after the installation too.

These are the first commands that I have run after the installation. Npm is in the path.
What am I missing here?
I tried reinstalling, and setting the environment variables.

You likely have a path issue where ng is not the CLI bin.

What about "ng --version" with the flag

What is the output from PushD C:\Users\thetest && (%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe .:ng & PopD)?

Seems like path issue, open (control panel -> system -> Advance system setting  -> Environment Variables ) or search for "Edit the system environment variables"
in Windows search. now make sure you have (%appdata%\npm) and (%ProgramFiles%\nodejs) in path column.

Then check for the sequence above if it is


%ProgramFiles%\nodejs
%appdata%\npm


Then try to change it by


%appdata%\npm
%ProgramFiles%\nodejs

Close cmd if it is open and try to reinstall the package. for more information look into npm docs.

If ng was not found in %PATH%, there would be a visible error message, "'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" This answer does not solve the reported problem.
